# Getting Writer error on using TinyLog

Tags: tinylog

I tried using TinyLog for a sample application to make sure understanding how it works, so that i can use it for my work application.

But, while using i get an exception to type cast the Writer (Compile time error). If i typecast it, it throws runtime error as below.

## Code :

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.pmw.tinylog.Configurator;
import org.pmw.tinylog.Logger;
import org.pmw.tinylog.writers.ConsoleWriter;
import org.pmw.tinylog.writers.Writer;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configurator.defaultConfig().writer(new ConsoleWriter()).addWriter((Writer) new FileWriter("data.txt")).activate();
        Logger.info("welcome to tinylog logger.....");
    }
}
```

## Error :-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.FileWriter cannot be cast to org.pmw.tinylog.writers.Writer
    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:12)

Please help us :).

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it easily. Just import `org.pmw.tinylog.writers.FileWriter` instead of `java.io.FileWriter`. The class `java.io.FileWriter` is the file writer of the JVM, but you need tinylog's file writer.

Afterwards you can remove the class cast "`(Writer)`" as  `org.pmw.tinylog.writers.FileWriter` is an implementation of the interface `org.pmw.tinylog.writers.Writer`. However the class `java.io.FileWriter` does not implement the interface `org.pmw.tinylog.writers.Writer`. Therefor the reported ClassCastException has been thrown.

```
import org.pmw.tinylog.Configurator;
import org.pmw.tinylog.Logger;
import org.pmw.tinylog.writers.ConsoleWriter;
import org.pmw.tinylog.writers.FileWriter;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configurator.defaultConfig().writer(new ConsoleWriter()).addWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt")).activate();
        Logger.info("welcome to tinylog logger.....");
    }
}
```